# SQL data query to join tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a SQL database query where I need to get the mark of a student. More specific: I need to JOIN all the way through mark, subject, studentsubject, student because I cannot just select all the marks, but marks from a specific subject, from a specific student. Any ideas?

I made just a trash request that select all the marks because of fail. I will be thankful for any help.

[database diagram](http://prntscr.com/8uvru3).

My original query:

```
SELECT Value 
FROM Mark 
JOIN Subject ON Mark.SubjectID = Subject.ID 
JOIN StudentSubject ON StudentSubject.subjectID = Subject.ID 
JOIN Student ON StudentSubject.studentID = Student.ID 
WHERE Student.NameStudent = 'Mira'
```

Comment: Not a clue what you are asking.  Please show:  sample input data, and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do joins like this and modify your filtering as needed:

```
select
   st.namestudent,
   st.surname,
   c.nameclass,
   su.namesubject,
   m.value
from studentsubject ss
inner join student st on st.id = ss.studentid
inner join subject su on su.id = ss.subjectid
left join mark m on 
  ss.studentid = m.studentid
  and ss.subjectid = m.subjectid
left join class c on
  c.id = st.classid
where
  st.namestudent = 'Mira'
  and su.namesubject = 'Science'
  and c.classname = '10A'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student St, Mark M, Subject Su
WHERE St.ID = M.StudentID
  AND M.SubjectID = Su.ID
  AND St.NameStudent = 'me'
  AND Su.NameSubject = 'sql';
```

I'd be wary of a relationship diagram with loops. Shouldn't the mark be in the Student[Takes]Subject table, or do you really need StudentSubject?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

"I cannot just select all the marks, but marks from a specific subject, from a specific student."
When you know the ID of the student and the ID of the subject (and you should, since they *uniquely identify* the entity; a name does NOT), then a simple `SELECT Value FROM Mark WHERE StudentID = ... AND SubjectID = ...` would suffice.

If you insist on making the selection based on names, then two joins are enough; one for the student, one for the subject.

```
SELECT Value
FROM Mark m
INNER JOIN Student st ON st.ID = m.StudentID
INNER JOIN Subject su ON su.ID = m.SubjectID
WHERE st.NameStudent = 'Mira'
  AND su.NameSubject = 'Math'
```

The table `StudentSubject` seems irrelevant in this context; it may be useful to register whether a student follows class, but it does not guarantee the presence of any mark. You could decide to let `Mark` refer to `StudentSubject` instead of the two separate tables, though. It would simplify your ER diagram.

Comment: Yeah, in this case StudentSubject really is irrelevant but it should be useful later in my task.